# What approach should I be using on getting random numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

3h of sleep and I cant figure this out... :S

I had a working something but I am changing the code a lot and removed it now I can not figure it back out.
I really need help...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 100.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">myFunction()</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">myFunction2()</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

var number2 = 0;
function myFunction() {
 number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var x = document.getElementById("demo")
    x.innerHTML = number2;
}
//number2 is still 0.
function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo2")
    x.innerHTML = number;
}

//number is stuck at the beginning number

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to generate new numbers from the myFunction2.
How do I achieve that ?

Comment: myfunction2( ) is generating new number every time. You should check your question once again.

Comment: @shaina Where does `myFunction2` generate a new number?

Comment: Source control is great spotting this kind of things!

Comment: @guest271314 Whenever I click on button myFunction2(), it gives a different number every time.

Comment: @shaina Your first comment references `myFunction2`, not `myFunction`

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, Edited the comment.

Comment: @shaina The JavaScript at Question does not change `number` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are already creating random numbers from using myFunction() and it doesn't seem like a problem. In myFunction2() you don't change or really *do* anything so how do you expect it to keep creating random numbers? Could you make your question a bit more clear?

Edit: Just place this line inside your myFunction2() instead of where you have kept it and it should work:

```
var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
```

Enter this before you actually assign anything to var x.

Answer (score 0):

`number` is defined once at JavaScript at Question. You can use the same approach that you did at `myFunction`, define `number` again within `myFunction2`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 100.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">myFunction()</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction2()">myFunction2()</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo2"></p>

  <script>
    var number = 0;

    var number2 = 0;

    function myFunction() {
      number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      var x = document.getElementById("demo")
      x.innerHTML = number2;
    }

    function myFunction2() {
      number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)
      var x = document.getElementById("demo2")
      x.innerHTML = number;
    }

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Lets say I have another function that needs that random number generated in myfunction() like this


function3(number2);

Comment: You need to pass `number2` to `function3` within `myFunction` call, after you have redefined `number2`

Comment: Within `myFunction2` `function3(numer2)` after you have redefined `number2`. Note that that is not original Question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask